# Malaysian e-Visa validity

Tags: indian-citizens, malaysia, e-visas

I have a 30-day single entry tourist e-Visa for Malaysia, expiring on November 14, 2018. I am going to Malaysia on November 9, 2018 and returning to India on November 14, 2018 from Malaysia, the same day my e-Visa expires. Can I travel with this visa?

Comment: Your visa is valid until 23:59 on 14 November. Exit before then and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Consulate General of Malaysia, Chennai FAQs](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_chennai/faqs)

> **When is the last date for Indian tourist to enter the country?**
>
> Indian tourist can enter the country till the day of visa expiry date provided the passport remains valid for not less than 6 months.